# Twitter Boostrap 4 : two toggler / displaying only one menu in lg screens

Tags: css, navigation, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using Twitter Boostrap 4 and have a navbar with 2 menus :

- one menu for the general navigation
- one menu for the account

On small devices, no problem : the two togglers are displaying correctly
[image]

On large devices, i want to show only the general navigation and not the account navigation. My problem : the account navivation is showing and i don't know how to hide it on large devices ?
[image]

```
<!-- logo -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" class="d-inline-block align-top"> 
    <img src="https://www.n9ws.com/images/upload/google-220118055200.png" />
</a>
<span class="d-none d-sm-inline" style="font-size:17px;text-shadow: 0.15em 0.15em #333;display:inline;color:white"><strong>Calendrier</strong> collaboratif des <strong>stages d'Aïkido</strong> en <strong>France</strong></span>

<!-- global menu toggle -->
<button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- account toggle -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" style="padding: 0.55rem 0.70rem;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMonCompte" aria-controls="navbarMonCompte" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</button>


<!-- account -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"  id="navbarMonCompte">
    <ul class="navbar-nav float-right text-right">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Change email</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Change password</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disconnect</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<!-- gloab menu  -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($this->menuSelected == 'accueil') ? 'active' : '';?>" href="/index2/index/">Accueil <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($this->menuSelected == 'calendrier') ? 'active' : '';?>" href="/calendrier2/calendrier/">Calendrier</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Enseignants</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Vidéos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comptes-rendus</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                A propos
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change email</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change password</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disconnect</a>
            </div>
        </li>            
    </ul>

    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0 btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal-connexion">
            Connexion
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Have you got an idea ?
Thank you.
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the navbar you want to hide by its id and give it a style of `display:none` to hide it on bigger devices i.e. `min-width: 992px`.

For eg: If you want to hide `navbarMonCompte`. The css will be as shown below.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #navbarMonCompte {
       display: none !important;
    }
}
```

**EDIT -** *To answer OP's new question in comments*

*On small devices, if i click on the 'account toggler" then on the 'global menu toggler', the 2 dropdown are shown. Is it possible to hide the other dropdow when a dropdown is shown ?*

```
$('button[data-target=my-modal-connexion]').click(function() {
    if($('#navbarSupportedContent').hasClass('show'))
        $('#navbarSupportedContent').removeClass('show');
});
```

The above-given jQuery will check if the navbar is open or not when the account toggler is clicked. If it is open, it will be closed.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.
The : .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-basis: auto;
}
is stronger.
I've added a image in the answer to show you.

Comment: Okay! Can you review your html code and rearrange the external stylesheets by adding the commun...v2 stylesheet at the end. After that include my updated style.

Comment: This stylesheet needs to be below the other stylesheet so that other css can be overridden.

Comment: the commun-v2.css is already at the end :

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.stages-aikido.fr/public/styles/bootstrap-custom-stages-aikido.css">

<!-- PNotify -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.stages-aikido.fr/public/js/lib/pnotify/pnotify.custom.min.css"> 

<!-- Custom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/commun-v2.css?time=1534773490"/>

Comment: It is working with the updated code. I just inspected the url you sent me and added the updated code. The link which you mentioned above is not having the updated code yet.

Comment: IT WORKS !!!!!! Thank you very much!!
It's strange because when i put the code in commun-v2.css, it doesn't work. But in <style>, it works!!

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL_PUBLIC;?>styles/bootstrap-custom-stages-aikido.css">

<!-- Custom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/commun-v2.css?time=<?php echo time();?>"/>

<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        #navbarMonCompte {
        display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>

Comment: A last question : on small devices, if i click on the 'account toggler" then on the 'global menu toggler', the 2 dropdown are shown. Is it possible to hide the other dropdow when a dropdown is shown ?

Comment: Updated my post with the answer to your new question. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `hide-account` class to the account button and put this into your css.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.hide-account {
    display: none;
}}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfto2qhw/1/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I put the navbar : <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end hide-account" id="navbarMonCompte"> but it doesn't work.
You can see : https://www.stages-aikido.fr/index2/videos/#

My goal is not to hide the account button. My goal is to hide the account navbar on large scrrens because i have already a dropdow for the account in the global navigation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `d-block d-md-none` to your `account Toggler` button you can use `d-sm-none` or `d-lg-none` instead of `d-md-none` as per your breakpoint

```
<!-- logo -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" class="d-inline-block align-top"> 
    <img src="https://www.n9ws.com/images/upload/google-220118055200.png" />
</a>
<span class="d-none d-sm-inline" style="font-size:17px;text-shadow: 0.15em 0.15em #333;display:inline;color:white"><strong>Calendrier</strong> collaboratif des <strong>stages d'Aïkido</strong> en <strong>France</strong></span>

<!-- global menu toggle -->
<button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- account toggle -->
<button class="navbar-toggler d-block d-md-none" style="padding: 0.55rem 0.70rem;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMonCompte" aria-controls="navbarMonCompte" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</button>


<!-- account -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"  id="navbarMonCompte">
    <ul class="navbar-nav float-right text-right">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Change email</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Change password</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disconnect</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<!-- gloab menu  -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($this->menuSelected == 'accueil') ? 'active' : '';?>" href="/index2/index/">Accueil <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($this->menuSelected == 'calendrier') ? 'active' : '';?>" href="/calendrier2/calendrier/">Calendrier</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Enseignants</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Vidéos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comptes-rendus</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                A propos
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change email</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change password</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disconnect</a>
            </div>
        </li>            
    </ul>

    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0 btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal-connexion">
            Connexion
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But  my goal is to hide the account navbar on large scrrens because i have already a dropdow for the account in the global navigation (i added a scrrenshot in my post)